# How to let a unit test ignore a middleware in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpunit, mockery

I'm testing an endpoint in my Laravel app. However, I have a middleware that does complex logic to determine the location of the user (using ip reverse look up etc such as this code:

```
public function getOpCityByIP()
{
    // Get the client's remote ip address
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) {
        $clientIpAddress = explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])[0];
    } else {
       $clientIpAddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    $opCityArray = OpCityIP::get($clientIpAddress);
    return $opCityArray;
}
```

I'm not interested in going inside the guts of such methods in said middleware and having to mock them etc. I'd rather simply skip the entire middleware during the unit testing, or at least mock its entire operations and instead hardcode the result to something predetermined. How do I do that?

I'm using Laravel 5.4

## update

i need it to ignore a specific middleware, not all of them

Comment: in your unit test you can disable middleware by using ```disableMiddleware()```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `withoutMiddleware()` method on your test object. As of Laravel 5.5, this method accepts a parameter that lets you specify which middleware to disable, instead of just disabling them all.

In your test:

```
$this->withoutMiddleware([YourGeoIpMiddleware::class]);
```

Comment: I'm using 5.4. I wonder if this alone merits an update to 5.5

Comment: @abhood Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34357350/how-to-disable-selected-middleware-in-laravel-tests/57401065#57401065). It has information on what to do if you're not on 5.5+ yet. After I answered here, I searched SO for similar questions, and found an older one that needed an updated answer. I wrote a more complete answer there, and I'll mark this question as a duplicate if that resolves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

To solve my problem of skipping *a specific middleware*, I simply put this code inside the handle method of said middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (config('app.env') === 'testing') {
        return $next($request);
    }
    ..
```

Comment: I don't know if this is a recommended way of doing it, but "config('app.env')" solved my issue. I needed to prevent a command from running when in test mode, that did the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    use WithoutMiddleware;

    // Stuff
}
```

Comment: i need it to ignore a _specific_ middle ware, not all of them

Comment: An important distinction in that update. In that case, you should use patricus' answer