# Call to a member function validated() on null (Unit testing Laravel 9)

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

I am writing test for some controller method that will validate request data and create document by 3rd party API. Then it should return response with `201` status code. I am using mocking to mock my service class that is creating document. Here is my controller:

```
public function margin(MarginRequest $request){
    $data = $request->validated();

    $fileId = $this->documentService->createDocument(auth()->user()->id, SignableDocumentAbstract::MARGIN_CERTIFICATE, new MarginDocument(), $data);

    return response()->json([
        'code' => 201,
        'message' => 'Margin agreement generated successfully',
        'data' => [
            'uuid' => $fileId
        ]
    ], 201);
}
```

And my test:

```
public function test_public_margin()
{
    $marginData = (new MarginFaker())->fake();

    Auth::shouldReceive('user')->once()->andReturn((object)['id' => 999999]);

    $this->mock(DocumentService::class, function (MockInterface $mock) {
        $mock->shouldReceive('createDocument')
            ->once()
            ->andReturn(Str::random());
    });

    $request = MarginRequest::create('/api/public/documents/margin', 'POST', $marginData);

    $response = app(PublicController::class)->margin($request);

    $this->assertEquals(201, $response->getStatusCode());
}
```

Everything look OK but when I run my test it throws error that

`Call to a member function validated() on null`

It is given in `$data = $request->validated();` line of controller. But I can't understand why my `$request` is recognized as null. Even if I dump request object by `dump($request)` I can see that it is object and holds all required fields inside.

Then what can be the reason, why I can't call `validated()` method while testing?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't make the response = "$this->post("{your url}", {your request data})", and then have the assertion be "$response->assertStatus(201)"?

Comment: @DanielHaven Can I make API request while using mock? Is it gonna fake the method I have defined or not?

Comment: API responses are meant to be mocked. If you're testing a method that can be accessed via HTTP, try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not test like that when you want to test a URL. You NEVER mock a controller or do `new Controller` and call a method inside it.

You have to read the [HTTP Test section of the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-tests).

So, your test should look like this:

```php
public function test_public_margin()
{
    $this->actingAs(User::factory()->create());

    $this->mock(DocumentService::class, function (MockInterface $mock) {
        $mock->shouldReceive('createDocument')
            ->once()
            ->andReturn(Str::uuid());
    });

    $response = $this->post(
        '/api/public/documents/margin', 
        ['pass the needed data as an array, so the validation passes']
    );

    $response->assertStatus(201);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I thought there is not that much difference between testing controller method by creating object or accessing it with API request. But I understood that if I call controller method directly, request class it not even fired to validate data. Thats why I will need to change my approach to API testing for controllers.

Comment: @VüsalHüseynli yes, but not only that, you are also not testing middlewares, they are important too!

Comment: @matiaslauriti If you're trying to test the controller itself, it's better to disable the middleware and test it in its own test.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34357350/how-to-disable-selected-middleware-in-laravel-tests

Comment: @DanielHaven I never had the need to do so, and I have been working with Laravel for 5+ years now. A feature test usually tests everything... unless you have a lot of middlewares, I would test the URL itself, because you must make sure you have what you need to have on that route, including middlewares... Check my profile (I have some SO answers on my bio) related to testing

Comment: @matiaslauriti My apologies.